# Neo4j - Relationship Modeling Issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 CSV files exported from mysql :

# Disease CSV Headers #
   Disease Master
   ID (autoincrement, pk) 
   disease_name

# Tests CSV Headers #
   Test Master
   ID (autoincrement, pk),
   test_name,
   parent_disease_ID (points to ID column in Disease.
    Master tbl)

I run following cypher commands :

```
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM.   
   "http://localhost/disease_mstr.csv" AS line
    MERGE (d:Disease {did: toInteger(line.ID),  diseasename: 
    line.disease_name})

    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM.  
   "http://localhost/test_mstr.csv" AS line
    MERGE (d:Tests {tid: toInteger(line.ID),  testname: 
    line.test_name, did: toInteger(line.parent_disease_ID)})

   MATCH (t:Tests), (d:Disease) CREATE (t:Tests)- 
   [r:TEST_FOR]->(d:Disease) RETURN t, r, d
```

Above cypher returns one disease connected to many tests whereas i want just the reverse!  Can someone please correct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the disease nodes, test nodes and relationship between test and disease nodes in one pass of the tests file.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "http://localhost/test_mstr.csv" 
AS line
MERGE (disease:Disease {did: toInteger(line.parent_disease_ID)})
MERGE (test:Tests {tid: toInteger(line.ID), testname: 
line.test_name})
MERGE (test)-[r:TEST_FOR]->(did)
```

And then update the disease names after the fact in a second pass.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "http://localhost/disease_mstr.csv" AS line
MERGE (d:Disease {did: toInteger(line.ID)})
SET d.diseasename = line.disease_name
```

Comment: Your solution didnt work, please find dave1.jpg output in my google folder. It also has sample csv files. [link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZrOW6WGiPZ66-r4nSgGO-GCcRK7HN1mO

Comment: Dave I managed to get 2 relationships  : (1) Diseases->Tests (2) Test->Diseases, Now I am only missing to connect these two relationships further, for example "Blood gases" Test is used for 5 diseases in GRAPH1, in other graph I have "Acidosis and Alkalosis" which having 10 other tests in GRAPH2, Now I want to connect realtionships in either of the GRAPHS, how to go ahead?  I have upload screenshots of both GRAPH VIEW and ROW VIEW in my google drive for you too look at.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

In the query that creates the relationships, you need to filter for `Tests` and `Disease` nodes that share the same `did` value:

```
MATCH (t:Tests), (d:Disease)
WHERE t.did = d.did
MERGE (t)-[r:TEST_FOR]->(d)
RETURN t, r, d;
```

This query also replaced `CREATE` with `MERGE` to avoid creating duplicate `TEST_FOR` relationships between the same `t` and `d` pair. If you already have such duplicate relationships, delete them first.

Also, for efficiency, you should consider creating in [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/schema/index/) on either `:Disease(did)` or `:Tests(did)` -- whichever has the most instances.

Comment: i already had tried with your solution and i am still getting 1 disease and many tests but i want vice versa, 1 test connected to 1 or more diseases in my test. Csv there are many repeated test names with diff parent_disease_id values for each of those!  Can you please review?

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you still have issues, provide some sample CSV files that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, its again showing 1 disease many tests heres the link to images, i am trying to get hold of csv sample files until then heres the link for review https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1ZrOW6WGiPZ66-r4nSgGO-GCcRK7HN1mO

Comment: Please link to my google drive folder with CSV files [link] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZrOW6WGiPZ66-r4nSgGO-GCcRK7HN1mO?usp=sharing)

Comment: Cybersam, managed to get 2 relationships  : (1) Diseases->Tests (2) Test->Diseases, Now I am only missing to connect these two relationships further, for example "Blood gases" Test is used for 5 diseases in GRAPH1, in other graph I have "Acidosis and Alkalosis" which having 10 other tests in GRAPH2, Now I want to connect realtionships in either of the GRAPHS, how to go ahead?  I have upload screenshots of both GRAPH VIEW and ROW VIEW in my google drive for you too look at.

Comment: Please create a new question with your new data model (which is very different than in this question), your new query, and a clear description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: As you said I posted with image and google drive link https://stackoverflow.com/q/50736680/8622150