# Neo4j Variable Depth not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, relationship

[image]I am trying to build a cypher query for two scenarios :

1. Tests having depth more than 2
2. Specific test having depth more than 2

As in Image you can see tests 1, 2, 3 are somewhat related through depth more than 2. The cypher which i ran was :

```
MATCH p=()<-[r:TEST_FOR*..10]-() RETURN p LIMIT 50
```

Now when i Change my cypher to below then i get no records/results or nodes.

```
1) MATCH p=()<-[r:TEST_FOR*2..5]-() RETURN p LIMIT 50
2) MATCH p=()<-[r:TEST_FOR*2]-() RETURN p LIMIT 50
3) MATCH p=(d:Disease)<-[r:TEST_FOR*]-(t:Tests) WHERE t.testname = 'Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)'  RETURN p
4) MATCH p=()<-[r:TEST_FOR*..10]-(t:Tests {testname:'Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)'}) RETURN p LIMIT 50
```

When I run Query 3 and 4 above, I get same results, i.e 1 test with 5 diseases, but it does not extend out further for that specific test.

But if you see the image the test is connected to two other tests ! My structure is as follows :

1. Tests (testname)
2. Disease (diseasename, did)
3. Linknode (parentdieaseid, testname)

I had used below query to create Relationship "TEST_FOR"

```
match(d:Disease), (l:Linknode) where d.did = l.parentdiseaseid
with d, l.testname as name
match(t:Test {testname:name}) create (d)<-[:TEST_FOR]-(t);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direction is the problem here. Each of your 4 queries above uses a *directed* variable-length matching pattern, meaning that every relationship traversed must use the direction indicated (incoming). However, that won't work once you hit :Tests nodes, since they only have outgoing relationships to :Disease nodes.

The easy fix is to omit the direction, so the matching pattern will traverse :TEST_FOR relationships regardless of direction. For example:

```
MATCH p=()-[r:TEST_FOR*2..5]-() RETURN p LIMIT 50
```

Note that the reason your original query

```
MATCH p=()<-[r:TEST_FOR*..10]-() RETURN p LIMIT 50
```

was returning the full graph is because it was never traversing deeper than a single hop from each :Disease node (since it would never be able to traverse an incoming :TEST_FOR relationship from a :Tests node), but it was starting from every :Disease node, so naturally that hit every single :Tests node as well. You would have gotten the same graph with this:

```
MATCH p=()<-[r:TEST_FOR]-() RETURN p LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon, That solves my Question 1, but what about Questions 2?, In queries 3 & 4 for testname = 'Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)' ??

Comment: @DaVinci007 Queries 3&4 look right to me. Try using `t.testname ~= '.*Alkaline.*Phosphatase (ALP).*'` If that works, then the error is that your match string does not match the property content. (probably white-space error in that case)

Comment: "MATCH p=(d:Disease)<-[r:TEST_FOR*]-(t:Tests) WHERE t.testname =~ '.*Alkaline.*Phosphatase.*(ALP).*'  RETURN p " - Nope, it does not branch out still shows 1 test and 5 diseases !

Comment: Ok just removed the incoming relationship arrow pointing to disease and it worked !!